# translation of "Ortsbogen"

Tags: geometry, mathematical-german

I'm teaching myself Geometry using a German-language textbook. My method is to translate the textbook into English, going through the theorems along the way.

I wanted to know what the accepted (standard) translation of the word "Ortsbogen" is. The concept is obvious enough, but searching through various English-language wikipedia articles linked from their German counterparts, and in various German-English dictionaries, has turned up nothing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could that German textbook actually be Swiss? It seems goolge presents mostly .ch links for "Ortsbogen", and "standard" German seems to prefer "Fasskreisbogen". -- Nevertheless, "Orts..." suggest to use "locus" in the translation. I too found that e.g. the English wikipedia seems to avoid the concept, e.g. ["For fixed points A and B, the set of points M in the plane for which the angle AMB is equal to α is an arc of a circle."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem) could be shortened a lot by using the word "locus". Suggestion: "Inscribed angle locus", "locus arc of (angle)"

Comment: It is indeed Swiss; it hadn't occurred to me that there might be regional variety among German-speaking mathematicians. Your suggestions are very good, assuming there is not some other term traditionally used in English.

Comment: I seem to have carried out the exact same search as Hagen von Eitzen, and reached the same conclusion (re: Swiss/German). Took me a bit longer, as I'm not a native speaker of German. Anyway, I did not find an English term for this circular arc either. Not sure there is a standard English term? [German WP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasskreisbogen).

Comment: https://www.mathematik.ch/anwendungenmath/Peripherie_Zentriwinkel/ortsbogen.html : In other words, yes, that is the same as Fasskreisbogen

Comment: Thank you both for your help!